# How to "if else" in Selenium (selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException)

Tags: python, selenium

What im trying to do now is Im checking whether button is disabled or not by selenium. If the button is disable it will keep refreshing the browser, it its not it will click on the button. But whenever I execute the program, it will show me some errors. Does anyone have any idea on this error ? Thanks in advance.

Errors:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\heng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/heng/PycharmProjects/testtest/Flash Sale Bot/bot.py", line 116, in startbot
    btnclass = belisekarang.get_attribute("class")
  File "C:\Users\heng\PycharmProjects\testtest\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 139, in get_attribute
    attributeValue = self.parent.execute_script(
  File "C:\Users\heng\PycharmProjects\testtest\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 634, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "C:\Users\heng\PycharmProjects\testtest\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\heng\PycharmProjects\testtest\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)
```

My Code:

```
def startbot():
    getproducturl = producturl.get()
    #getvaration = variation.get()
    gethour = timehour.get()
    gettime = timeminute.get()

    driver.get(getproducturl)
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath(getvaration).click()
    try:
        belisekarang = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div/button[2]')
        belisekarang.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.refresh()
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        print("fafaf")

    btnclass = belisekarang.get_attribute("class")

    while True:
        if 'disabled' in btnclass:

           driver.refresh()
        else:
            belisekarang.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
belisekarang =WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div/button[2]')))

    
btnclass = belisekarang.get_attribute("class")

while True:
    if 'disabled' in btnclass:

       driver.refresh()
    else:
        belisekarang =WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div/button[2]')))
        belisekarang.click()
```

after you call driver.refrresh() your dom structure gets refreshed and all element references are lost. so you have to re identify all elements again.

so in your case just add 'belisekarang' before getting the class again

Comment: Its worked, but it show me `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div/button[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)`

Comment: Does it mean the problem occured in my xpath ?, its seem like it wont refresh after search no element.

Comment: Ya recheck the xpath or add waits

Comment: Add wait and see , time.sleep(5) after the refresh

Comment: thanks it worked. So its probably refresh too fast and couldnt get the item tho

Comment: Btw it cant proceed to another line of code. It keep showing `line 122, in startbot
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
  File "C:\Users\heng\PycharmProjects\testtest\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: I need to put timeout exception ?

Comment: t=you have to refind the element inside the while loop also as your againing refreshoing

Comment: Its also the same error , timeout exception. I tried to figure it out myself first. Or maybe i will open a new thread about this issues.  Thank you